# Conditional AngularJS model binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way I can use conditional AngularJS data binding?

I want to bind my model to `vm.ABC` if bool has true value, if it has false, I want to bind my model to `vm.XYZ`.

Comment: and when does this condition happen, like at the time bootstraping or later

Comment: Check the answer, this is what you need

Comment: @Rakeschand at the time of bootstrapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ng-if` for this. Here is the simple example,

```
//if bool is true then bind vm.ABC
<input type='text' ng-if='bool' ng-model='vm.ABC' />

//if bool is false then bind vm.XYZ
<input type='text' ng-if='!bool' ng-model='vm.XYZ' />
```

This will work great for your condition. And also by using `ng-if` the HTML is not render on the UI if the condition is `false`.

Comment: This is not what OP asked, he is asking for ng-model binding, read the question again

Comment: That was just an example. However i have changed it.

Answer (score 3):

```
<div ng-init="vm.thirdVar = bool ? vm.ABC : vm.XYZ">
    <input type="text" ng-model="vm.thirdVar">
</div>
```

`vm.thirdVar` define this in controller

Comment: let me give it a try

Comment: are you using AngularJS or Angular2

Comment: I'm using AngularJs 1.6

Comment: Thanks for the help @Rakeschand